# Exchange token js api or php multi query

Tags: facebook, token

Is it possible to get users extendest tokens via js api?

If it isn't what about getting multiple users token with single query?

I get tokens like this;

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=".$u[token]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't issue an ajax request to that url since ajax requests are limited to your domain (cross-domain security policy), but you might be able to use the facebook javascript sdk, though I'm not sure it will work.

Something like:

```
FB.api("oauth/access_token", "get", {
    client_id: xxx,
    client_secret: xxx,
    grant_type: "fb_exchange_token",
    fb_exchange_token: currentToken
}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Even if this works, it's not something that you should use since you **have** to include the  app secret with the request, and since you want to do so from the client side it means that the app secret won't really be a secret no more.

Also, what's the point of doing that? As long as the user is interacting with your app, you can simply use what it states in [Handling Invalid and Expired Access Tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/):

> **Desktop Web and Mobile Web apps which implement authentication with
>   the Javascript SDK**
>
> Calling FB.getLoginStatus() or ensuring status: true is set when you
>   call FB.init() means that the next time a user lands on your
>   application and is signed into Facebook, the authResponse object you
>   are passed as a result of those calls will contain a fresh, valid
>   access token.
>
> In this case, its simply the act of the user using your application
>   which implicitly generates a new access token.

As for your other question, the facebook api has what's called [Batch Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/), which let you make a few api queries in one request, but I'm not sure that it work for the relative path "oauth/access_token", but you are welcome to try it.

Comment: @Nitaz Tomer ... I am getting.  Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment. i followed the same syntax

Comment: @RED.Skull that's a js error.. you probably did something wrong, probably used one `=` for comparison instead of two or three (`==` or `===`).
If you can't solve it I suggest that you post a completely new question about it, though there are probably a few that already exist on the subject